# Non-pointwise convergence of $f_k(x) = x^k(1-x)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm having difficulties in disproving pointwise convergence of

$$f_k(x) = x^k(1-x)$$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Specifically I don't know how I'm supposed to do anything with the definition of pointwise convergence:

$$\forall x \in D : \forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R} : \exists N \in \mathbb{R} : |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$

Since I cannot really plug anything to $f(x)$ in order to make $|f_n(x)-f(x)| > \epsilon$?

I have no other definitions (or theorems for that matter) than this.

Comment: What is the domain of the $f_k$?

Comment: For any $x _0 > 1$ (or $x < -1$), the sequence $f_k(x_0)$ is unbounded.

Comment: Certainly it converges pointwise at $|x|\le0$ but it doesn't anywhere for $|x|>1$. What have you tried already?

Comment: @DanRobertson Well I have no idea what I could use as the limit function.

Comment: @mavavilj Pick a point and try it?

Comment: @DanRobertson Is the limit function necessarily a single real number?

Comment: There is only a limit function if your sequence converges. There is no limit function as the sequence does not converge. If you are looking for a limit not-a-function then try setting it to 0 for all $|x|<1$, $+\infty$ for $x>1$, 0 for $x=1$, undefined at $x=-1$ and undefined infinity at $x<-1$.

Comment: @DanRobertson Well I obviously need some $f(x)$ to do anything with $|f_n(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon$? But how can I pick it?

Comment: Perhaps you could tell me what precisely you think it means for a sequence of functions to converge pointwise. Would you give a different definition for "a sequence of deals converges" from "a sequence of real numbers converges to $x$"?

Comment: @DanRobertson The definition is here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Pointwise_Convergence, but to make any use of it I need some $f(x)$?

Comment: @mavavilj I didn't ask you because I don't know what it means. I was hoping that you would write down the definition that you have memorised and in doing so you would see how to solve the problem yourself. I would define pointwise convergence for some sequence $f_1,f_2,\dots$ as: $\forall x\quad (f_1(x),f_2(x),\dots)\text{ converges}$. Perhaps you could write down the definition that you have memorised for what it means for a sequence of real numbers to be convergent.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to stem from the fact that you, like many beginners, confuse the expression *"to have a limit"* with the expression *"to be convergent"*. Let us clarify things a bit.

If $(x_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers, we say that it *converges* to $x$ if and only if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exist $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $|x_n - x| < \varepsilon$ for every $n \ge N$. Take a good look at this! Now, try to put $\infty$ instead of $x$ in the above definition: do there exist values of $\varepsilon > 0$ for which $|x_n - \infty| < \varepsilon$? Obviously not, because this would mean $\infty < \varepsilon$, and $\varepsilon$ was taken by definition to be a real number, therefore finite. What is the conclusion of this? The conclusion is that if $(x_n)$ *converges* to $x$, then $x$ is necesarily a real number (hence finite).

What about the sequence $x_n = n$? Doesn't it converge to $\infty$? No, according to the above definition, it doesn't. What it does is that *it tends to $\infty$* - but it is not *convergent* to $\infty$!

Keep this in mind:

- you say that a sequence *has a limit* if it has a *finite or infinite* limit;
- you say that a sequence is *convergent* if it has a *finite* limit.

If a sequence is convergent, then it has a limit. The converse is not necessarily true: if a sequence has a limit, then it does not necessarily converge (think of $x_n = n$).

---

What about sequences of functions? Well,

- we say that a sequence of functions $f_n : D \to \Bbb R$ *has a pointwise limit* if and only if for every $x \in D$ the sequence $(f_n (x))$ *has a limit*;
- we say that the sequence $(f_n)$ is *pointwisely convergent* if and only if for every $x \in D$ the sequence $(f_n (x))$ is *convergent*.

In both cases, if we define $f(x) = \lim \limits _{n \to \infty} f_n (x)$, then we say that $f_n \to f$ pointwisely. Pay attention, if $(f_n)$ *tends to $f$ without being convergent to $f$*, then $f$ may be infinite in some points! On the other hand, if $(f_n)$ *converges* to $f$, then $f$ is guaranteed to be finite.

---

Concerning your problem, notice that if $x>1$ then $\lim \limits _{k \to \infty} x^k = \infty$ and, since $1-x < 0$, it follows that $\lim _{k \to \infty} x^k (1-x) = -\infty$, therefore there is no function that $(f_k)$ *converges* to for $x>1$ (the "constant function" equal to $\infty$ is, in fact, not a function). It is true that $f_k \to -\infty$, but according to the discussion above, this is not called convergence!

The problem is even worse when $x \le -1$. In this case, $1-x > 0$, but $x^k$ does not converge when $k \to \infty$. The reason is simple: the sequence $(x^k)$ has two subsequences:

- the subsequence corresponding to even $k$ tends to $\infty$;
- the subsequence corresponding to odd $k$ tends to $-\infty$.

We know that a sequence that has subsequences tending to different limits does not have a limit; in particular, it cannot be convergent.

---

To summarize: the sequence $x^k (1-x) : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$

- does not have a limit on $(-\infty, -1]$, therefore does not converge on this interval;
- converges to $0$ on $(-1, 1]$;
- tends to (bot does not converge to) $-\infty$ on $(1, \infty)$.

In particular, since $(f_k)$ does not converge on $(-\infty, -1] \cup (1, \infty)$, it also will not converge on $\Bbb R$ (because if $(f_k)$ converges on some set $A$ it must also converge on all the subsets $B \subseteq A$, which clearly does not happen here).

Comment: How can you say that "there's no function that $f_k$ converges to"? Why does the limit being infinity mean that?

Comment: There's no **real-valued** function that $f_k$ converges to, because $\infty$ is not a real value.  It converges to $\infty$ in the [extended reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line).

Comment: @RobertIsrael: True, but since we usually have our functions form a vector space, I work under the *usual* assumption of them not taking infinite values (otherwise we would quickly get to $\infty - \infty$ and $0 \cdot \infty$).

Comment: @mavavilj: The explanations included in my edit should clarify for you the difference between "having a limit" and "being convergent".